# wso2 esb + api management

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-esb

I need to integrate WSO2 API MANAGER with an external ESO2 ESB, but don't know which configuration should I set up.

I know API MANAGER has a greg, should I mount ESB'registry to it? Also API MANAGER has an ESB, can I just share configuration of the external ESB with the API MANAGER's ESB?

Please Help!!

**EDIT**: the goal is to achieve a clustered environment with API MANAGER, but looks like the typical deployment configuration with a central registry (http://wso2.org/project/esb/java/4.0.3/docs/deployment_guide.html) does not work with API MANAGER, why?

**EDIT2:** the official page clearly says: "Horizontally scalable with easy deployment into cluster using proven routing infrastructure." i.e. "API manager can be integrated with others API managers" but is not really easy: while enabling cluster is matter of change a value in the axis2.xml the deployment synchronization does not work, or at least for me it doesn't. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

The ESB components which are used in API manager used to manage SLA and acts as a gateway. DO NOT ADD external ESB configurations in API manager.
This is the documentation for API manager.It has clear guideline on how to add, what are the components etc..

http://docs.wso2.org/wiki/display/AM100/API+Manager+Components

Comment: My problem is that I know how to cluster ESBs but if I cannot add an ESB to API manager how can I cluster the API Managers together? Should I use a central registry? Looks impossible... I have enabled clustering in the "axis2.xml" and deployment synchronizer but this is not enough to share configuration right? Thank you again

Comment: Clustering of what?..You can do ESB clusters..But i dint get what you mean by API+esb cluster.. DO you want to point same registry for API mgr and ESB?..it is not best practice

Comment: I would like to cluster more than one API manager: API_1+API_2+API_3 but how? I will use ESB outside the cluster, is it better practise?

Comment: Yes you need keep ESB as separated one. I dont think clustering available for API manger. Since this is the very first release, that feature is yet to be added .